# Java text to speech I can't get it to talk

Tags: java, windows, text-to-speech

I have been trying to make a text to speech program i'm on a windows pc just for reference. I can't get my program to say what i've told it to. If someone can help me fix this or point me to a resource that will help me fix it, it will be much appreciated

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class javatalker extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField textfield = new JTextField(35);
        JButton button = new JButton("Push To Talk");
        JCheckBox checkbox1 = new JCheckBox("Normal");
        JCheckBox checkbox2 = new JCheckBox("Blitzcrank");



    public javatalker() {

        panel.add(textfield);
        panel.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if(textfield.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    System.out.println("Typle in a string");
                } else{
                    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                    try{

                        if(checkbox1.isSelected() == true){
                            Process p = rt.exec("say" + textfield.getText());
                        }
                        if(checkbox2.isSelected() == true){
                            Process p = rt.exec("say -v Cellos" + textfield.getText());
                        } else{
                            System.out.println("Please select a voice");
                        }
                    }catch(Exception ex) {
                        ex.getStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        panel.add(checkbox1);
        panel.add(checkbox2);
        panel.setBackground(Color.black);
        add(panel);

        setTitle("Voicip");
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new javatalker(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the "say" command works on Windows. I believe it's OS X only.

Comment: do you have any idea what it is for windows

Comment: I've never used it, but this question might be able to help: http://superuser.com/questions/223913/os-x-say-command-for-windows

Answer (score 2):

`say` command does not exist on windows.

You could create a script

```
@echo off
echo Dim Speak >> %HOMEPATH%\speak.vbs
echo Set Speak=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice") >> 
%HOMEPATH%\speak.vbs
echo Speak.Speak "%1">> %HOMEPATH%\speak.vbs
%HOMEPATH%\speak.vbs
del %HOMEPATH%\speak.vbs
```

pasted from https://superuser.com/questions/223913/os-x-say-command-for-windows

Name the script **speak.bat** and put it in `C:\Windows\system32`

Then modify

```
Process p = rt.exec("say" + textfield.getText());
```

to

```
Process p = rt.exec("speak" + textfield.getText());
```

You might also have a look at [`espeak`](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) which is open-source.

Comment: where in the system 32 would i put it

Comment: @poketis directly in the system32 folder.

Comment: ty make it a bat file yes

Comment: Not sure to understance your sentence(?) but yes, make it a bat file.